# Add leading zeros only if the number starts with 6 in R dataframe

Tags: r, formatting, digits

I have a dataframe with numbers that I need to format. How do I add leading zeroes to only numbers that starts with 6? All examples seen using `str_pad()` or `sprintf()` are not exactly like my task, and I found it challenging to adapt them. My dummy dataframe is below:

```
dummy_numbers
621103 
06102658  
19562106    
61102
0635467
```

The desired result is:

```
desired_numbers
0621103 
06102658  
19562106    
061102
0635467
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that however you do this, the numbers are stored as type `character` and the leading zero will be lost if you force them to be numeric.

Comment: `gsub("^6", "06", vec)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## dplyr

Your can use `grepl()` and regex (`^`) to capture the start of a string.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(dummy_numbers = ifelse(grepl("^6", dummy_numbers), 
                                     paste0(0, dummy_numbers), 
                                     dummy_numbers))
```

Or simply use a `gsub()` or `sub()`

```
df %>% mutate(dummy_numbers = gsub("^6", "06", dummy_numbers))
```

## base R

```
df[, "dummy_numbers"] <- gsub("^6", "06", df[["dummy_numbers"]])
```

Comment: Isn't your edit `gsub("^6", "06", dummy_numbers))` what @r2evans has already suggested in his answer?

Comment: Kind of integrate it in a data frame instead of vector

Answer (score 5):

We just need a simple "leading-6" regex:

```r
gsub("^6", "06", dummy)
# [1] "0621103"  "06102658" "19562106" "061102"   "0635467" 

identical(gsub("^6", "06", dummy), desired)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Data

```r
dummy <- c("621103", "06102658", "19562106", "61102", "0635467")
desired <- c("0621103", "06102658", "19562106", "061102", "0635467")
```

Answer (score 4):

You may add 0 to only those numbers that start with 6. This can be written as -

```
transform(df, dummy_numbers = 
              paste0(ifelse(grepl('^6', dummy_numbers), "0", ""), dummy_numbers))

#  dummy_numbers
#1       0621103
#2      06102658
#3      19562106
#4        061102
#5       0635467
```

Without `ifelse` -

```
inds <- grepl('^6', df$dummy_numbers)
df$dummy_numbers[inds] <- paste0(0, df$dummy_numbers[inds])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `str_replace` to capture numbers starting with `6` then replace with `06`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(dummy_numbers = str_replace(dummy_numbers, "^6", "06"))
```

**Output**

```
  dummy_numbers
1       0621103
2      06102658
3      19562106
4        061102
5       0635467
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(dummy_numbers = c(
    "621103", "06102658", "19562106", 
    "61102", "0635467"
  )),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```